# Android: Sidescrolling using canvas.translate

Tags: android, 2d, side-scroller

I'm developing a 2D sidescroller game, but I don't really know how to implement the sidescrolling feature.
I've heard, that using canvas.translate everytime the hero moves is one possibility, but OpenGL is also considered sometimes.
I draw every single bitmap at a specified position using coordinates..so just moving the canvas won't work, will it?